# Components overlapping in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm doing a project using React and Django and currently I have a problem where two components (Header and NavBar) are overlapping. I know this is extremely easy, but I've already tried lots of approachs and I can't still figure this out.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="Appli">
        <Header/>
        <NavBar/>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
export default App;

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

**NavBar.js**

```
export default function NavBar() {

  const displayNavBar = () => {
    return (
    
    <Drawer 
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        <List >
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <EditIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Overview" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ListIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Tasks" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ContactMailIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drivers" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <LocalShippingIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Vehicles" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <BookmarksIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Plans" />
        </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    );
  };

  return (
      <div >{displayNavBar()} </div>
  );

}
```

**Header.js**

```
export default function Header() {

  const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (<Toolbar >
      <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>
      Tenant One
            </Typography>
      <IconButton aria-label="settings" >
        <SettingsIcon/>
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton aria-label="person" >
        <PersonIcon/>
    </IconButton>
    </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <AppBar position="fixed" className="appbar">{displayDesktop()}</AppBar> 
    </header>
  );

}
```

**CSS file**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Wraps app div  */
#main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

/* Where the react code is being rendered */
#app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header{
    display:flex;
    background-color: orange;
    
}


.Appli{
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here is the final result.

[image: Problem]

Thanks in advance for the help. Like I mentioned before, this is probably really easy to solve. I'm just terrible with CSS and HTML.

Comment: give some width to Header component

Comment: This is using MUI library? Have you followed their example of what you are trying to achieve? https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answers. Yes, I'm using material-ui and I was following that   tutorial. I even experimented messing with the z-index. I also tried to add 100% width to the Header. Didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

In `AppBar`, change `position` prop to `static`;

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem continues.